# java string to utc date

Tags: java, date

This question is a *duplicate* of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7113357/java-parse-utc-time-string) by intention. It seems like the older one is "ignored", while none of the answers there is the answer.

I need to parse a given date with a given date pattern/format.

I have this code, which is *supposed to* work:

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class Main
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        final Date date = string_to_date("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy",
                "Thu Aug 14 16:45:37 UTC 2011");
        System.out.println(date);
    }

    private static Date string_to_date(final String date_format,
            final String textual_date)
    {
        Date ret = null;

        final SimpleDateFormat date_formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(
                date_format);
        try
        {
            ret = date_formatter.parse(textual_date);
        }
        catch (ParseException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return ret;
    }
}
```

For some reason I'm getting this output:

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Thu Aug 14 16:45:37 UTC 2011"
    at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:337)
    at Main.string_to_date(Main.java:24)
    at Main.main(Main.java:10)
null
```

What's wrong with my date pattern? This seems to be a mystery.

Comment: Just look in the documentation of [SimpleDateFormat](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Comment: I think new Date('Thu Aug 14 16:45:37 UTC 2011'); actually works

Comment: @True Soft I did, several times, and still can't figure out the pattern I need. Why not write it down? I'd appriciate it.

Comment: Your code worked fine for me. I just copied and pasted and ran it.

Comment: Please **DO NOT** ask the same question again just because you aren't getting any useful responses to the original. Update the original question instead or offer a bounty.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your platform default locale is apparently not English. `Thu` and `Aug` are English. You need to explicitly specify the [`Locale`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html) as [2nd argument in the constructor of `SimpleDateFormat`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#SimpleDateFormat%28java.lang.String,%20java.util.Locale%29):

```
final SimpleDateFormat date_formatter = 
    new SimpleDateFormat(date_format, Locale.ENGLISH); // <--- Look, with locale.
```

Without it, the platform default locale will be used instead to parse day/month names. You can learn about your platform default locale by [`Locale#getDefault()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html#getDefault%28%29) the following way:

```
System.out.println(Locale.getDefault());
```

Comment: Great answer. Never even occurred to me to think about the EEE and MMM

Comment: Man, you just rock! That was the issue. THANKS!

Answer (score 1):

This should parse the given string.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException
{
    String sd = "Thu Aug 14 16:45:37 UTC 2011";


    String dp = "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy";

    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(dp);

    Date d = sdf.parse(sd);

    System.out.println(d);

}
```

Comment: Yes I tested, what error are you getting. Just be informed that the last sysout would print date in your OS timezone (not in UTC). You might have to use SimplateDateFormat for getting the date string in other than default timezone.

Comment: I get the 'ParseException'. That's very weird. And the code is so simple - no place for typo etc'..

Answer (score 0):

I should have specify a locale, like this:

```
final SimpleDateFormat date_formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(date_format, Locale.ENGLISH);
```

Thanks to [BalusC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/157882/balusc) with his [great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7114742/java-string-to-utc-date/7114771#7114771)!